# Change Odoo tree lines format

Tags: xml, view, format, odoo, erp

Anyone knows if it's possible to change in Odoo ERP the way to visualize tree lines in the views.
For example, to change/format lines width or height.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc8uV.png)
Thanks!

Comment: You can change how tree [any other Odoo feature] visualize by adding theme. Refer Odoo  themes for how to create them https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user change the column width, you can install this module [Resize column](https://odoo-community.org/shop/product/resize-columns-4644?maturity=production%2Fstable).
Please note the module is available for version 11 and 12.

Best,